# Undefined variable when it is defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I keep getting this error **Undefined variable: checkInDate** when I already define it.

```
public function checkAvailable(Request $request){
    $checkInDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->start_date));
    $checkOutDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->end_date));

  $availableRooms = availableRoom::whereHas('reservation',function($query){
        $query->where(function($query){
            $query->whereDate('reservationDate', '>=', $checkInDate);
            $query->whereDate('reservationDate', '<=', $checkOutDate);
        })->orWhere(function($query){
            $query->whereDate('expiryDate', '>=', $checkInDate);
            $query->whereDate('expiryDate', '<=', $checkOutDate);
        });
    })->get();

    return $availableRooms;

}
```

The checkInDate already has a value. Am I miss something?

Comment: You need to add `use ($checkInDate, $checkOutDate)` to the anonymous function: `..whereHas('reservation',function($query) use ($checkInDate, $checkOutDate) {...`

Comment: Both the $checkInDate and $checkOutDate is getting the same error Undefined variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a use () added to each function so that the variable is accessible to the function else it only has access to the variables that get passed into.

```
public function checkAvailable(Request $request){
    $checkInDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->start_date));
    $checkOutDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->end_date));

  $availableRooms = availableRoom::whereHas('reservation',function($query) use ($checkInDate, $checkOutDate) {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($checkInDate, $checkOutDate){
            $query->whereDate('reservationDate', '>=', $checkInDate);
            $query->whereDate('reservationDate', '<=', $checkOutDate);
        })->orWhere(function($query) use ($checkInDate, $checkOutDate){
            $query->whereDate('expiryDate', '>=', $checkInDate);
            $query->whereDate('expiryDate', '<=', $checkOutDate);
        });
    })->get();

    return $availableRooms;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to access the variable within a callback you need to pass the variable to the callback with `use` statement.

```
public function checkAvailable(Request $request){ 

$checkInDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->start_date)); 

$checkOutDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->end_date)); 

$availableRooms = availableRoom::whereHas('reservation',function($query)use($checkInDate, $checkOutDate){ 
    ...
});
```

Since your also trying to use `$checkOutDate` you will also need to pass it through to the callback as well, separating it with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
 $availableRooms = availableRoom::whereHas('reservation',function($query){
```

by:

```
 $availableRooms = availableRoom::whereHas('reservation',function($query) use($checkInDate,$checkOutDate) {
```